# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems

Tags: java, testing, time, import, message

I am having a problem importing classes and setting variables and I need help with a test program I am doing. So I am testing out a program that just simply outputs what your input was and puts a time stamp ( Like Skype ). I am having an issue getting the message and time variable type to work! Here is my code:

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Message messageObject = new Message ();
        Time timeObject = new Time ();

        System.out.println("Enter your message here: ");
        String message = input.nextLine();

        messageObject.simpleMessage(message);
        timeObject.getTime();
    }

    void simpleMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println(message + time);
    }
}
```

And here is my error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
Message cannot be resolved to a type
Message cannot be resolved to a type
The constructor Time() is undefined

at Test.main(Test.java:8)
```

Comment: What part of the error messages don't you understand? They seem clear to me.

Comment: Where is your Message class? Also, you probably wanted `java.util.Date` - what Time class do you have?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Message cannot be resolved to a type
 Message cannot be resolved to a type

 at Test.main(Test.java:9)

Comment: I changed time to date now that is fixed but I am still getting errors with message!

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Message cannot be resolved to a type
 Message cannot be resolved to a type

 at Test.main(Test.java:9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in this line: `Message messageObject = new Message ();`
This error says that the `Message` class is not known at compile time.

So you need to import the Message class.

Something like this:

```
import package1.package2.Message;
```

Check this out.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html

Comment: Can you guys pls send me a screenshot of the edited java file! I don't understand and I am very new to java! Thanks everyone though for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities here. 
Java Version incompatible or import

Answer (score -1):

You have to Import the Scanner and Timer Package Properly using the java.util classes.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Timer;
```

Answer (score -1):

For this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problems:

There are problems with your import or package name.
You can delete the package name or fix import errors

Answer (score -1):

The error may be happening while calling the method.
You are calling simpleMessage function with the object of a different class.
Since simpleMessage method is inside the class Test. First, you have to create the object of the Test class.

To create the object of class Test

```
Test simpleMessageObject = new Test();
```

To call simpleMessage method

```
simpleMessageObject.simpleMessage(message)
```

Answer (score -2):

Check Following :
1) Package names
2) Import Statements (import every required packages)
3) Proper set of braces  ,i.e { } 
4) Check Syntax too.. i.e semicolons,commas,etc.